# In Bash, how to find with a PATH like variable

Tags: bash, cd-command

Say I have `CDPATH` which contains paths I want to `cd` to in case it is not found in `.`

Without using `cd` itself how do I get the first path that would satisfy it using `bash`

The purpose of which is to make `cd` do a `pushd` as `pushd` does not support `CDPATH` at least on this version of bash I am using.  It works on other bashes though

Comment: Please explain "satisfy it". I'm unsure what "it" is and what you mean by "satisfy".

Comment: If I wasn't a moderator, I would vote this question as "unclear" (as a moderator, that would close the question at once, so I don't, because maybe I'm just a bit thick). Could you please give an example of what you are wanting to do, what your variable is, and explain if the `cd` or `find` utilities have _anything_ to do with your question?

Comment: Do you mean _given some value of `$CDPATH`, what directory would `cd foo` take me to?_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your concern regarding the use of `cd` is *actually* about moving the current shell's working directory, then you could use command substitution, which executes the `cd` in a subshell that harmlessly disappears:

```
d=$(cd some-name)
```

For example:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/{a..d}
$ CDPATH=/tmp
$ cd /
$ pwd
/
$ dir=$(cd c)
$ printf '%s\n' "${dir%/*}"
/tmp
$ pwd
/
```

Here I've captured the output from `cd c` on the assumption that an entry in `CDPATH` satisfies it. That result is the new working directory, so in order to return the corresponding path entry from `CDPATH`, I use parameter expansion to remove the last forward slash onwards -- essentially, the name of the deepest directory. It transforms `/tmp/c` to `/tmp` above.

Comment: Actually using the `cd` utility to change the directory is the most robust way of resolving what directory would be picked (note that `cd` may not output the new working directory, use `pwd` for that). Trying to implement this _without_ using `cd` [as I tried to do](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509951/116858) is error prone.

Comment: I'll have to flesh this out a bit, as `cd` prints the new directory _if_ it used CDPATH to get there, but not otherwise. "If a non-empty directory name from CDPATH is used, or if ‘-’ is the first argument, and the directory change is successful, the absolute pathname of the new working directory is written to the standard output."

Comment: `d=$( cd some-name && [ -z "$CDPATH" ] && pwd )`  ?

Comment: I don't get that thing about the stdout showing the path with your answer @JeffSchaller

Comment: @Archimedes - I'd be happy to explain, but I'm not sure yet what you're asking about. The part where I echo out the value of `$dir` after removing the deepest directory name?

Comment: I mean I don't see anything in stdout which you said you had to fix when I ran it.  Your answer works as it is.

Comment: Happy to hear that! I was worried about the situation where the user would enter an absolute path name, such as `cd /tmp/foo` or `cd ./subdirectory`; in that case, the `cd` command would *not* output the new directory to stdout, which is what Kusalananda's comment was addressing. If that situation is possible, let me know, and we can try to update the answer to account for it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you mean

> Given some value of `$CDPATH`, what directory would `cd foo` take me to? Can this be found without using `cd`?

Ok, so `cd foo`, when `$CDPATH` is set, would look at each of the `:`-delimited values in `$CDPATH` to try to find a subdirectory called `foo`.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$1
cdpath=${2:-$CDPATH}

if [ -z "$cdpath" ] && [ -d "$dir" ]; then
    printf '"cd %s" would take you to %s\n' "$dir" "$dir"
    exit
elif [[ $dir == /* ]] || [[ $dir == ./* ]] || [[ $dir == ../* ]]; then
    # special cases where $CDPATH is not used
    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        printf '"cd %s" would take you to %s (ignoring $CDPATH)\n' "$dir" "$dir"
        exit
    else
        printf 'Did not find destination directory for %s\n' "$dir"
        exit 1
    fi
fi

while [ -n "$cdpath" ]; do
    subdir=${cdpath%%:*}/$dir
    if [ -d "$subdir" ]; then
        printf '"cd %s" would take you to %s\n' "$dir" "$subdir"
        exit
    fi
    [[ $cdpath != *:* ]] && break
    cdpath=${cdpath#*:}
done

printf 'Did not find destination directory for %s\n' "$dir"
exit 1
```

This script would look at the `CDPATH` variable value given as its secod argument (or in its environment) and try to figure out where `cd` would take you when its destination directory is given as the first argument on the script's command line.

Since `CDPATH` *should not be exported*, this script would have to be invoked as either

```
CDPATH=$CDPATH ./script.sh dir-name
```

or as

```
./script.sh dir-name "$CDPATH"
```

The script first tests whether `$CDPATH` is empty.  If it is, `cd dir` would take you to `dir` in the current directory. It also hondles some special cases that should bypass the use of `$CDPATH`.

If `$CDPATH` is not empty, the script starts to pick off the elements from its value, one by one, to see whether the named directory exists as a subdirectory of any of the paths mentioned.

The first value is picked by deleting from the first `:` in `$cdpath` to the end of its value. `$cdpath` is later set to the value you get by deleting up to the first `:`.  This way, the loop progresses through the paths in `$cdpath` and only exits if a valid directory is found or if there finally are no further `:` characters in the string.

If we get past the loop we have failed to find a valid destination to `cd` to.

Note: My code does not handle all cases.  See the relevant bits in [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/cd.html).

Answer (score 1):

How about the command:

```
 $ find `echo $CDPATH|sed 's/://'` -name 'whatever' -print
```

Comment: A `PATH`-like variable contains `:`-delimited paths.  `$CDPATH` would be a `:`-delimited string of directory paths. `find` would not be able to use it as its search path.

Comment: good catch....corrected to remove : characters from variable name

Comment: This would unfortunately still split the value of `$CDPATH` on spaces, and invoke filename globbing on the bits.  And the `echo` may additionally interpret backspaces. (sorry to be a pain)